# Please update the FAQ links

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

Now that it appears that [the official parent FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq) has been migrated from SO to MetaSO, shouldn't the link to the FAQ at the end of [the main FAQ page](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) link to it instead of [the stub remaining on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-unofficial-faq)?

Even though many of the subcomponents of the official FAQ still link back to SO for the time being, the newest versions of the subcomponents that *have* been migrated are only linked from the MetaSO parent FAQ, not the stub on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sites now link to

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=faq&sort=votes

so make it count!

Comment: the link is currently http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq, so you don't get them sorted by votes. This should be fixed as most voted faq post is  the list of faq posts

Answer (score 1):

Probably should finish migrating the linked FAQs first... 20 users... or 1 moderator... could do it in a day if properly motivated.

Who wants to chip in on tasty insects for Bill?

Comment: I was going to just append meta in front of all of the urls, until i realized that all of the question numbers didn't match. 'Edit fail'

Comment: Ahhh, I failed to notice only a few were migrated. I guess the handful I checked just happened to be the ones that were moved already. However, the since the "parent" FAQ has been moved, the link to it from the main page could still be pointed to MetaSO even if subcomponents of the FAQ are still on SO.

Comment: @gnovice: yeah, probably - might encourage new questions to be posted here as well i guess. @jjnguy: lol... would be nice if they did keep the same numbers, but probably not feasible.