# FAQ link to meta-FAQ should sort questions by votes

Tags: feature-request, faq-update-request

In the [site-specific-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) site, the [What about...](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#what-about) section links to the meta-SE faq, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq. This is useful if you land on highest voted question tagged faq (then you get the [faq post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) on top, but the link doesn't say it, so you can land on the faq listed by activity.

I found in an [old answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10452/please-update-the-faq-links/11707#11707) that the link was, once upon a time, sorted by votes.

This old post is tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but it should be reopened.

Can we revert back to a link that sorts faq by votes?